# Vue js 2 : this.$emit dont Trigger

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I has a simple code to test comunicate between child and parent component follow example from vuejs doc : http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events. but apparently it does not work at the parent component

My jsfiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thanhmabo/1m2100p9/8/)

**html:**

```js
Vue.component('tasks-item', {
       template: '<div>{{item.title}} <button v-on:click="deleteItem(item)">x</button></div>',
       props: ['item'],
       methods: {
        deleteItem: function(item){
          console.log('child click')
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML='child click : '+item.title
            this.$emit('deleteItem')
         }
       }
})


Vue.component('tasks-list', {
       template: '#tasks-list',
       props: ['tasks'],
       methods: {
        deleteTask: function(){
          document.getElementById('output').innerHTML='parent click'
         }
       }
})


new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  data: function(){
   return {
     data:[{"id":51,"title":"rr4434","content":"rtrtrrtrtr"},{"id":50,"title":"rrrr","content":"rrr"},{"id":49,"title":"rrrr","content":"rrr"},{"id":48,"title":"rrr","content":"rrr"},{"id":47,"title":"rrr","content":"rrr"},
{"id":46,"title":"c\u00f4 d\u00e2\u0300n","content":"pha\u0309i khong em"},
{"id":45,"title":"we are you","content":"content"},
{"id":44,"title":"cai min nek","content":"co gi kh\u00f4ng"},{"id":43,"title":"abc","content":"dghjj"},{"id":42,"title":"dddd","content":"ddd"},{"id":38,"title":"444","content":"4444"},{"id":36,"title":"rrr","content":"rr"},{"id":35,"title":"rr","content":"rr"},{"id":34,"title":"rrrr","content":"rrr"},{"id":33,"title":"rrr","content":"rr"}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <div id="output">click output</div>
   <hr/>
    <tasks-list :tasks="data"></tasks-list>
</div>
<template id="tasks-list">
     <div>
        <div v-for="item in tasks">
           <tasks-item :item="item" v-on:deleteItem="deleteTask()"></tasks-item>
        </div>
     </div>
</template>
```

Comment: In 2 you need to use an event hub. The documentation says to use a vue instance as the hub so you can either create a lib that exports a new vue instance and import that into each component that needs to communicate or you can just use the root instance with this.$root.$emit and this.$root.$on from any component since they all share the same root

Comment: Thanks, I 'll have a look and I 'll try it , i'll let u know cheers

Comment: @vbranden: Thanks, $root helped!

Comment: Making an event bus is much better than using $root

Answer (score 0):

Change
`this.$emit('deleteItem')`
to
`this.$emit('delete-item')`

and inside template fix component's v-on from
`v-on:deleteItem`
to
`v-on:delete-item`

You can read more at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html